# Manipulação do HashMap entre classes (Interpretação e Aplicação)

Tags: java, classes, hashmap

é minha primeira pergunta, desculpe a extensão, estou dúvidas no seguinte exercício:

> Crie uma classe Pizza que possua o método adicionaIngrediente() que
>   recebe uma String com o ingrediente a ser adicionado. Essa classe
>   também deve possuir o método getPreco() que calcula da seguinte forma:
>   2 ingredientes ou menos custam 15 reais, de 3 a 5 ingredientes custam
>   20 reais e mais de 5 ingredientes custa 23 reais.
>
> É preciso contabilizar os ingredientes gastos por todas as pizzas!
>   Utilize uma variável estática na classe Pizza para guardar esse tipo
>   de informação (dica: utilize a classe HashMap para guardar o
>   ingrediente como chave e um Integer como valor). Crie o método
>   estático contabilizaIngrediente() para ser chamado dentro de
>   adicionaIngrediente() e fazer esse registro.
>
> Crie uma nova classe chamada CarrinhoDeCompras que pode receber
>   objetos da classe Pizza. Ela deve ter um método que retorna o valor
>   total de todas as pizzas adicionadas. O Carrinho não pode aceitar que
>   seja adicionada uma pizza sem ingredientes.
>
> Crie uma classe Principal com o método main() que faz o seguinte:
>
> - Cria 3 pizzas com ingredientes diferentes;
> - Adiciona essas Pizzas em um CarrinhoDeCompra;
> - Imprime o total do CarrinhoDeCompra;
> - Imprime a quantidade utilizada de cada ingrediente.

Estou com dificuldades para entender o que é pedido, principalmente em relação à listagem dos ingredientes pelo HashMap, pelo que eu entendi na classe Pizza vou criar os métodos pedidos no exercício, e no adicionaIngredientes() vou receber ingrediente a ingrediente e contabilizar pelo contabilizaIngrediente() a quantidade de ingredientes de cada pizza e enviar para o getPreco().

Tendo o valor individual, vou enviar o objeto pizza para a classe CarrinhoDeCompra, que vai validar se a pizza tem ingredientes ou nao, se sim, vai somar ao valor total. Na classe principal vou adicionar as pizzas e os ingredientes de cada uma, e exibir o valor total e a quantidade de cada ingrediente, correto?

Complementando, no HashMap como isso será passado e contabilizado na classe Pizza, já que ele trabalha com o Key e o Value somente e parece ser do tipo Integer? Como esses dados sao manipulados para variáveis separadas? Se alguem puder me dar um exemplo semelhante com a manipulação entre classes eu agradeço muito, pois nao achei nada parecido na internet, só exemplos relacionados a classe main(). Até o momento fiz isso:

```
        public class Pizza {

        static int ingredienteTotal = 0;
        public String ingrediente;
        public int quantidadeContador;
        public int preco = 0;


        static int contabilizaIngrediente(int quantidade){
            ingredienteTotal += quantidade;

            return ingredienteTotal;            
        }

        public String adicionaIngrediente(String ingrediente) {
            contabilizaIngrediente(quantidadeContador++);
            this.ingrediente += ingrediente;
            return ingrediente;
        }

        public int getPreco(){
            if (contabilizaIngrediente(quantidadeContador)<= 2){
                 preco = 15;
                }
            else if (contabilizaIngrediente(quantidadeContador)>= 3 
                    & (contabilizaIngrediente(quantidadeContador)<= 5)) {
                 preco = 20;
                }

            else if (contabilizaIngrediente(quantidadeContador)< 5){
                 preco = 23;
        }
            return preco;
        }

        public void imprimeQuantidadeIngrediente(){
            // aqui teria que imprimir qual ingrediente e sua quantidade individual, mas nao sei como fazer
        }
    }

public class CarrinhoCompras {

    int precoTotal;

    public void adicionaPizzas (Pizza p){
        //validando se há ingredientes
        if (p.quantidadeContador != 0)

            this.precoTotal += p.getPreco();
        else

            System.out.println("Pizza sem ingredientes");

    }
    //imprime o preço de todas as pizzas    
    public void imprimeTotal(){
        System.out.println("O preço total é: " + precoTotal);

    }


}

import java.util.HashMap;


public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //instanciando uma lista de ingredientes
        HashMap <String, Integer> ingrediente =  new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        //preenchendo a lista
        ingrediente.put("manjericão", 2);
        ingrediente.put("queijo", 3);
        ingrediente.put("tomate", 2);
        //criando uma nova pizza
        Pizza p1 = new Pizza();
        //tentando inserir o ingrediente por String, mas o método identifica como Integer
        p1.adicionaIngrediente(ingrediente.get("manjericao"));


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Uma resposta possível

Abaixo um código para você usar de base para o seu exercício. O ideal é você olhe o código, entenda cada parte e depois faça do zero a partir do seu entendimento. A parte mais complexa está em usar a classe `HashMap` porém através da documentação do Java você poderá entender como funciona essa coleção.

O enunciado não está completo. Ele deixa confuso o que realmente se deseja como resposta. O melhor é você conversar com quem passou o exercício para entender melhor a questão e adaptar o código de acordo.

```
import java.util.*;

class Pizza
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> ingredientes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void adicionarIngrediente(String ingrediente, Integer qtde)
    {
            // nao verifica se o mesmo ingrediente ja foi adicionado e vai substituir nesse caso
            ingredientes.put(ingrediente, qtde);
    }

        // descobre se a pizza esta sem ingredientes
    public int getQtdeIngredientes() {
            return ingredientes.size(); 
    }

        // calcula o preco da pizza conforme a regra de qtde de ingredientes
    public int getPreco()
    {
            Integer total = 0;

            for (Integer value : ingredientes.values()) {
                Integer preco = 0;
                if (value <= 2) {
                        preco = 15;
                } else if (value <= 5) {
                        preco = 20;
                } else {
                        preco = 23;
                }
                total += preco;
            }

            return total;

    }

        // retorna os ingredientes para que possa fazer a soma dos ingredientes de todas as pizzas
        public HashMap<String, Integer> getIngredientes()
        {
            return ingredientes;
        }
}

class CarrinhoDeCompras 
{
        // lista de pizzas que foram adicionadas no carrinho
    private List<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList<Pizza>();

    public void adicionaPizza(Pizza pizza) {
            if (pizza.getQtdeIngredientes() > 0) {
                pizzas.add(pizza);
            }

    }

        // calcula o preco total das pizzas do carrinho
    public Integer getTotalPreco() {
            Integer total = 0;
            for (Pizza item : pizzas) {
                total += item.getPreco();   
            }
            return total;
    }

        // contabiliza as quantidades de todos os ingredientes de todas as pizzas        
    public HashMap<String, Integer> getIngredientes() {
            HashMap<String, Integer> cesta = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (Pizza item : pizzas) {
                HashMap<String, Integer> ingredientes = item.getIngredientes();
                for (String key : ingredientes.keySet()) {
                    Integer total = ingredientes.get(key);
                    if (cesta.containsKey(key)) {
                        total += cesta.get(key);
                    }
                    cesta.put(key, total);
                }
            }

            return cesta;
    }

}

/**
 *
 * @author vagnerp
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Pizza muzzarela = new Pizza();
        muzzarela.adicionarIngrediente("Tomate", 1);
        muzzarela.adicionarIngrediente("Queijo", 3);
        muzzarela.adicionarIngrediente("Azeitona", 5);

        Pizza margerita = new Pizza();
        margerita.adicionarIngrediente("Tomate", 1);
        margerita.adicionarIngrediente("Queijo", 3);
        margerita.adicionarIngrediente("Manjericao", 2);
        margerita.adicionarIngrediente("Azeitona", 2);

        Pizza portugueza = new Pizza();
        portugueza.adicionarIngrediente("Tomate", 1);
        portugueza.adicionarIngrediente("Queijo", 2);
        portugueza.adicionarIngrediente("Ovo", 2);
        portugueza.adicionarIngrediente("Azeitona", 5);
        portugueza.adicionarIngrediente("Prezunto", 2);

        CarrinhoDeCompras carrinho = new CarrinhoDeCompras();
        carrinho.adicionaPizza(muzzarela);
        carrinho.adicionaPizza(margerita);
        carrinho.adicionaPizza(portugueza);

        System.out.println("Total do Preco do Carrinho: " + carrinho.getTotalPreco());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Qtde Ingredientes");
        System.out.println("=================");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : carrinho.getIngredientes().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Essa lógica me ajudou muito, pelo que havia visto em outros exercicios o HashMap só era usado na main(), acreditei que esse era o padrão, uma dúvida, porque nas comparações você está usando Integer e não int? Troquei aqui e não deu nenhum erro até agora.

Comment: @PaolaFarias O HashMap é uma forma de resolver e acho que a ideia do exercício e dar a oportunidade de conhecer essa classe. O "Integer" é uma classe e o "int" é tipo primitivo. Usar a classe ao invés de um primitivo tem algumas vantagens como poder associar um nulo, serializar, fazer parse de strings, etc. No caso desse exercício não tem essas necessidades, então acho que usar o int vai funcionar sem problemas.